# Error While trying to Deploy Flutter Web App on cPanel: "We're sorry, but something went wrong.."

Tags: node.js, flutter, web, cpanel

I have followed the steps in this [article](https://medium.com/firebits/deploy-flutter-web-app-in-a-shared-hosting-with-nodejs-5f7bc820b18d) to deploy flutter app as node.js app. My app directory in the server is: home/username/app/app,
and here is what I entered to create node.js app:

[image]

and when I visit the web app url that's what I get:

[image]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate Flutter web build files using the following command. Hit it on your terminal:

```
flutter build web
```

It will generate files at **your_project/build/web/** location. You need to upload all the files to cPanel at **public_html** folder. It has index.html file, which will run in your browser with its dart javascript library. You don't need any third server with Node.js or python.

Detailed explanation at: [How to Deploy Flutter Web App on cPanel Shared Hosting](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/160/how-to-deploy-flutter-web-on-cpanel-shared-hosting/)

Answer (score 0):

Web applications are specially used for server side requests.

You have to export your web page with the command "flutter build web" and then copy all the files generated and put them into public_html folder.